# Is there a way to monitor progress of a btrfs resize?

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, btrfs

I'm shrinking a large btrfs partition using `btrfs filesystem resize -xxxx /mountpoint`.
The resize progress is really slow, is there anything like a progress bar?

Comment: Interesting question!  I'm not aware of of any progress meter, but I'm wondering what `watch -d btrfs filesystem` `df/usage/show` `/mountpoint` might look like.  A progress meter might first find the total number of blocks that need to move and then monitor the move progress.

Comment: @rickhg12hs As far as I can tell, none of those commands reveal information that one could use to reliably determine the resize progress.

Comment: @ATLief During a `resize`, none of filesystem stats are available/updated?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The reported filesystem size changes as soon as the resize begins, even if the "allocated" data is larger than that. The "unallocated" data doesn't necessarily predict the current progress.

Comment: @ATLief Interesting, good to know. I wonder if there is something in the kernel that could be monitored and perhaps "monkey-patched" with `stap` to make it visible in user land.

Answer (score 0):

A negative `Unallocated` can be used as an indicator of the amount of data that needs to be moved.

Tested on Debian 10 with Linux 4.19.0-25 and btrfs-progs v4.20.1.

Examples:

```
$ btrfs filesystem usage /mountpoint
Overall:
    Device unallocated:           -1.30TiB
Unallocated:
   /dev/sda1    -1.30TiB
```

```
$ btrfs device usage /mountpoint
/dev/sda1, ID: 2
   Unallocated:            -1.30TiB
```

Use `-g` or `-m` to show sizes in GiB or MiB respectively for more precision.

Run `btrfs filesystem usage` or `btrfs device usage` without specifying the mountpoint to see other available CLI parameters.